# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So, going into the problem straight away. someone told me that we dont need to make a `pivot table` if we only want to have `ids` of the table. laravel can itself handle this situation. I dont know how this works. I have a table `community` and another table `idea`. relation is like this;

> One community can contain many ideas and an idea can be found in many
>   communities.

**Relation in idea Model:**

```
 public function community() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Community')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Relation in community Model:**

```
 public function idea() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\idea');
    }
```

Now i want to fetch all the records related to a single community to show on its page Let's say the community is `Arts`.

**Here is Controller function:**

```
 public function showCommunities($id) {
    $community = Community::findOrFail($id)->community()->get();
    return view('publicPages.ideas_in_community', compact('community'));
   }
```

When i attach `->community()->get()` to the  `Community::findOrFail($id)` Then it throws the error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found laravel

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Logically, this piece of code `Community::findOrFail($id)->community()->get()` should be like this `Community::findOrFail($id)->idea()->get()`. Now it is true but it has little issue. it throws an error

> Fatal error: Class 'App\idea' not found

Comment: Are you sure the code above is correct? You're trying to fetch a community from a community with Community::findOrFail($id)->community()->get() and there is no community relation in Community model. Besides, for a many-to-many relationship you DO NEED an intermediate table to store the relation.

Comment: i am not sure about the relation thats why i have posted them here to get help from seniors like you. someone who has experience in laravel said we dont need an intermediate table if we only want to store their `ids` laravel can itself manage it. I have also tried `Community::findOrFail($id)->community()->get()` it says `App/idea` is not found. But i have included it @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: You might have misunderstood what the person was saying. Indeed, Laravel doesn't require you to define an intermediate Model class, but it does require you to have an intermediate table. I'll post the answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the many-to-many relation looks ok - I'd just call them **communities()** and **ideas()**, as they'll return a collection of objects, not a single object.

Make sure you use correct class names - I can see you refering to your model classes using different case - see **App\Community** and **App\idea**.

In order to find related models, Eloquent will look for matching rows in the pivot table - in your case it should be named **community_idea** and have 3 fields: **community_id**, **idea_id** and autoincrement primary key **id**.

With that in place, you should be able to get all ideas linked to given community with:

```
$ideas = Community::findOrFail($communityId)->ideas;
```

If you need communities linked to given idea, just do:

```
$communities = Idea::findOrFail($ideaId)->communities;
```

You can read more about how to use many-to-many relationships here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

> someone told me that we dont need to make a pivot table if we only want to have ids of the table

The above is not true (unless I've just misunderstood).

For a many-to-many (`belongsToMany`) their must be the two related table and then an intermediate (`pivot`) table. The intermediate table will contain the primary key for table 1 and the primary key for table 2.

In laravel, the convention for naming tables is plural for your main tables i.e. `Community` = 'communities' and `Idea` = 'ideas'. The pivot table name will be derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names i.e.
`community_idea`.

Now, if you don't want/can't to follow these conventions that's absolutely fine. For more information you can refer to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Once you're happy that you have the necessary tables with the necessary fields you can access the relationship by:

```
$ideas = $community->ideas()->get();

//or

$ideas = $community->ideas;
```

So you controller would look something like:

```
public function showCommunities($id)
{
    $community = Community::findOrFail($id);

    //The below isn't necessary as you're passing the Model to a view
    // but it's good for self documentation

    $community->load('ideas');

    return view('publicPages.ideas_in_community', compact('community'));
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the ideas to the array of data passed to the view to be a bit more verbose:

```
public function showCommunities($id)
{
    $community = Community::findOrFail($id);

    $ideas = $community->ideas

    return view('publicPages.ideas_in_community', compact('community', 'ideas));
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

I would imagine the reason that you're receiving the `App\idea` not found is because the model names don't match. It's good practice (and in certain environments essential) to Capitalise you class names so make sure of the following:

1. Your class name is `Idea` and it's file is called `Idea.php`
2. The class has it's namespace declared i.e. `namespace App;`
3. If you've added a new class and it's not being found you might need to run `composer dump-autoload` from the command line to update the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your valuable time. Could you tell me how can i display `ideas` of `community` on `ideas_in_community` view? I have tried it but it shows nothing. i am using third choice of function you have listed above. @Ross Wilson

Comment: What have you tried so far to display the ideas within that view? Can you add a copy of what you have in your `view` to your question?